# Break subfigures along 2 pages using the subfigure package

Tags: floats, page-breaking, subfloats

I am trying to add subfigures that are larger than one page. I am using the package `subfigure` that might be a bit obsolete, indeed, however I insist in using it because I have a very large documents and it's hard to make the necessary changes.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2800\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2800120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2800\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2800120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=3300\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron3300120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=3300\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron3300120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 %\label{fig:CompCrosSec}
 \caption{alsfjnv;jakf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

Is there a way to make it break along 2 pages using something similar to `\ContinueFloat` from `subfig` package?

Comment: `subfigure` is deprecated. Use `subfig` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : I have a very large document with many subfigures and it will be a bit messy to apply all the changes.

Comment: `subfig` is described as 'com­pletely back­ward com­pat­i­ble with' `subfigure` so I don't think you would need to make any changes ;).

Comment: But they seem to be lying :(.

Comment: @cfr : they really seem to be lying! Thank you! :P

Answer (score 3):

The documentation suggests that there is a `subfigure.cfg` file which you can use to make `subfig` compatible with `subfigure`. However, I could not get this to work. (`subfigure.cfg` appears to be part of `subfigure` judging by its location in my `texmf` tree?)

The following helps a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[config=altsf]{subfig}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2800\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2800120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2800\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2800120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=3300\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron3300120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=3300\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron3300120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \caption{alsfjnv;jakf}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \ContinuedFloat
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \subfigure[$\delta E-E$, $E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120CAMAC}}\hfill
 \subfigure[$E_p=2250\;keV$]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Boron2250120NIM}}
 \caption[]{alsfjnv;jakf continued}
 %\label{fig:CompCrosSec}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but the results are not exactly perfect:

[image: imperfection with subfig]

So I'm not sure this will be very helpful.